# Reusing vertices to pass into shader

Tags: c#, graphics, xna, 3d

General question:

Let's say you have a list of vertices that you pass into an effect to draw something, based on shader parameters (for example, laser width or whatever). I want to pass in the same vertices, but with different shader parameters - this however, does not work.

Here is the code in question:

```
           foreach (EffectPass pass in quinticFX.CurrentTechnique.Passes)
            {
                quinticFX.Parameters["NumPoints"].SetValue(CurvedVertices.Count());
                pass.Apply();
                GraphicsDevice.SamplerStates[0] = LinearMirrorState;
                GraphicsDevice.Textures[0] = solid;

                quinticFX.Parameters["radiusOfBeam"].SetValue(8);
                GraphicsDevice.DrawUserPrimitives<VertexPositionTexture>(PrimitiveType.TriangleStrip, CurvedVertices.ToArray(), 0, CurvedVertices.Count() - 2);
                pass.Apply();

                quinticFX.Parameters["radiusOfBeam"].SetValue(4);
                quinticFX.Parameters["P"].SetValue(cp1);
                GraphicsDevice.DrawUserPrimitives<VertexPositionTexture>(PrimitiveType.TriangleStrip, CurvedVertices.ToArray(), 0, CurvedVertices .Count() - 2);
            }
```

I *assumed* you could do this, and it would draw the (in this case, a curve) with different control points and width, twice. This is not the case - only the most recent set of primitives is drawn. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I am an idiot - you need to Apply() the pass after setting parameters.

The corrected code is as follows:

```
foreach (EffectPass pass in quinticFX.CurrentTechnique.Passes)
{
    quinticFX.Parameters["NumPoints"].SetValue(CurvedVertices.Count());
    //GraphicsDevice.SamplerStates[0] = SamplerState.LinearWrap;
    GraphicsDevice.SamplerStates[0] = LinearMirrorState;
    GraphicsDevice.Textures[0] = solid;

    quinticFX.Parameters["radiusOfBeam"].SetValue(12);
    pass.Apply();
    GraphicsDevice.DrawUserPrimitives<VertexPositionTexture>(PrimitiveType.TriangleStrip, CurvedVertices.ToArray(), 0, CurvedVertices.Count() - 2);

    quinticFX.Parameters["radiusOfBeam"].SetValue(6);
    quinticFX.Parameters["P"].SetValue(cp1);
    pass.Apply();
    GraphicsDevice.DrawUserPrimitives<VertexPositionTexture>(PrimitiveType.TriangleStrip, CurvedVertices.ToArray(), 0, CurvedVertices.Count() - 2);

    quinticFX.Parameters["radiusOfBeam"].SetValue(3);
    quinticFX.Parameters["P"].SetValue(cp2);
    pass.Apply();
    GraphicsDevice.DrawUserPrimitives<VertexPositionTexture>(PrimitiveType.TriangleStrip, CurvedVertices.ToArray(), 0, CurvedVertices.Count() - 2);
}
```